# How to relate $\sum_{n=0}^k a_nf(n)$ where $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ is a bijection to the sum $\sum_{n=0}^k a_nn$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

suppose you're give these two sums: $\sum_{n=0}^k a_nf(n)$ where $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ is a bijection and $\sum_{n=0}^k a_nn$. is it possible to relate them in any way?

Comment: If $f$ is linear then $f\left(\sum_{n=0}^k a_n n\right) = \sum_{n=0}^k a_n f(n)$. Otherwise, I don't think you can relate them.

Comment: @ClementYung And specifically $f=id$.